# Centering UILabel in UITableViewCell using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout

I am new to Auto Layout in Xcode so I need your help.

I have custom tableView cell with one UILabel on the left and three on the right and I want them to be centered like this :

[image]

(the dash line represents center of the cell).

So I want that left label to be centered on the left side, and right three cell to be centered on the right side.

Further more I would like to be able to remove one of the three labels on right side of the cell and centered remaining two of them. 
(in the code). Like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just put my logic.. use frame of all label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
LeftLabel.frame = CGRectMake((((cell.frame.size.width/2)-yourLabelWidth)/2, ((cell.frame.size.height-yourLabelHeight)/2, yourLabelWidth, yourLabelHeight));

CGFloat rightLblX = ((cell.frame.size.width/2) - (5*yourTotalNumberOfLabel))/2;

rightLabel_one.frame = CGRectMake(rightLblX, ((cell.frame.size.height-yourLabelHeight)/2, yourLabelWidth, yourLabelHeight);

rightLblX = rightLblX + 5;

rightLabel_two.frame = CGRectMake(rightLblX, ((cell.frame.size.height-yourLabelHeight)/2, yourLabelWidth, yourLabelHeight);

rightLblX = rightLblX + 5;

rightLabel_three.frame = CGRectMake(rightLblX, ((cell.frame.size.height-yourLabelHeight)/2, yourLabelWidth, yourLabelHeight);
```

Comment: That is not using autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go pal:

For left label,
1. Ctrl+drag from label to cell & select "Centre vertically in container".
2. Ctrl+drag from left label to cell & select "Centre horizontally in container".
3. If the placement is not correct by 2nd step, undo 2nd one & select "leading space from container".

This much is enough for left label.

for right labels,
Repeat the same steps for each label.. This will solve your issue. Let me know if You still need some help.. :)

Comment: Yes I need more help :D By step 2 you place left label in the center of the cell but I would like to center in in the left half of the cell. By stem 3. you specify how much is the distance from the left border and if cell grow bigger this would not stay in center of the left half.

Comment: Actually auto layout does not have such features like having "centre of left half or right half." you have to programmatically calculate the distance in each orientation. For rotation also, you have to do the same.. :(